# What is weblogic.socket.Muxer?

Tags: java, sockets, weblogic, weblogic8.x, muxer

Does any of you understand what weblogic.socket.Muxer is used for in WebLogic 8.1?

Often in thread dumps I see stack traces similar to this:

```
"ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=20 idx=0x68 tid=26709 prio=5 alive, in native, blocked, daemon
    -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x2b673d373c50[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1675)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1776)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1312)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1259)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2439)[optimized]
    at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
```

It's not that I have any problems with that, it is just intresting to understand:

1) what is it doing? 
2) can it affect any performance?

Comment: The word "muxer" is a contraction of the word "multiplexer". The thing you're seeing is an internal Weblogic class. Sorry, I don't know why you get those errors.

Comment: It's not an error, it just a stack trace cut from a thread dump.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/perform/WLSTuning.html#wp1152246):

> WebLogic Server uses software modules
>   called muxers to read incoming
>   requests on the server and incoming
>   responses on the client. These muxers
>   are of two primary types: the Java
>   muxer or native muxer.
>
> A Java muxer has the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - Uses pure Java to read data from sockets.
> - It is also the only muxer available for RMI clients.
> - Blocks on reads until there is data to be read from a socket. This behavior does not scale well when there are a large number of sockets and/or when data arrives infrequently
>     at sockets. This is typically not an  issue for clients, but it can create a huge bottleneck for a server.
>
> Native muxers use platform-specific
>   native binaries to read data from
>   sockets. The majority of all platforms
>   provide some mechanism to poll a
>   socket for data. For example, Unix
>   systems use the poll system and the
>   Windows architecture uses completion
>   ports. Native provide superior
>   scalability because they implement a
>   non-blocking thread model. When a
>   native muxer is used, the server
>   creates a fixed number of threads
>   dedicated to reading incoming
>   requests. BEA recommends using the
>   default setting of selected for the
>   `Enable Native IO` parameter which
>   allows the server automatically
>   selects the appropriate muxer for the
>   server to use.
>
> If the `Enable Native IO` parameter is
>   not selected, the server instance
>   exclusively uses the Java muxer. This
>   maybe acceptable if there are a small
>   number of clients and the rate at
>   which requests arrive at the server is
>   fairly high. Under these conditions,
>   the Java muxer performs as well as a
>   native muxer and eliminate Java Native
>   Interface (JNI) overhead. Unlike
>   native muxers, the number of threads
>   used to read requests is not fixed and
>   is tunable for Java muxers by
>   configuring the `Percent Socket Readers`
>   parameter setting in the
>   Administration Console. See [Changing
>   the Number of Available Socket
>   Readers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/perform/WLSTuning.html#wp1152595). Ideally, you should configure
>   this parameter so the number of
>   threads roughly equals the number of
>   remote concurrently connected clients
>   up to 50% of the total thread pool
>   size. Each thread waits for a fixed
>   amount of time for data to become
>   available at a socket. If no data
>   arrives, the thread moves to the next
>   socket.

Then, for those reasons, it is obviously better to use native muxers.

Here, it looks like you are using the default native muxer (`weblogic.socket.EPollSocketMuxer`), not the Java muxer (`weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer)`.

Answer (score 7):

I have found [this link](http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/05/weblogic-socket-muxers-are-not-stuck.html) that explained the situation pretty much:

> The socket Muxer manages the server’s
>   existing socket connections. It first
>   determines which sockets have incoming
>   requests waiting to be processed. It
>   then reads enough data to determine
>   the protocol and dispatches the socket
>   to an appropriate runtime layer based
>   on the protocol. In the runtime layer,
>   the socket muxer threads determine
>   which execute thread queue to be used
>   and delegates the request accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

For any given application server, a thread dump will show you hundreds, if not thousands, of background threads. These servers are complex beasts, and these threads are just the background plumbing doing its job.

A "muxer" is a multiplexer, which is a mechanism for combining several streams of data on to a single channel. Weblogic will be using these to exchange data with itself, or with other nodes in the cluster. At any given time, a number of those will be "blocked", since they have nothing to do.

It's almost certainly no cause for concern. If you look under the rock, you're bound to find a few ugly things underneath blinking up at you in the sunlight.